# Configure shiro.ini for JDBC connection

Tags: apache, shiro

As part of my new years learning new technologies initiative I have started messing around with the Apache Shiro Security Framework.

I managed to get the basic example working which stores usernames, passwords and roles in the shiro.ini file, but when I modified my shiro.ini file to use JDBC it just stopped working. I now keep getting prompted for my username and password when trying to access my application. I've kept it as simple as possible (the passwords aren't even hashed).

Below is my shiro.ini file, does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
[main]
authc.usernameParam = j_username
authc.passwordParam = j_password
authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true

jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?"
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = "SELECT role FROM user WHERE username = ?"

ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
ds.serverName = localhost
ds.user = root
ds.password = password
ds.databaseName = database
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

# Use Built-in Chache Manager
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

[users]
[roles]
[urls]
/* = authcBasic
```

Comment: Can you try removing the quotes from your queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not giving permission query then better disable permission lookup.  Also if you want to use basic Authentication why use authc attributes.

Try Following

```
    [main]
    #authc.usernameParam = j_username
    #authc.passwordParam = j_password
    #authc.failureKeyAttribute = shiroLoginFailure

    jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
    jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = false

    jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = ?
    jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT role FROM user WHERE username = ?

    ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
    ds.serverName = localhost
    ds.user = root
    ds.password = password
    ds.databaseName = database
    jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds

    # Use Built-in Chache Manager
    builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
    securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

    securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm

    [users]
    [roles]
    [urls]
    /* = authcBasic
```