# Vertx shiro auth from a database

Tags: java, shiro, vert.x, vertx3

[Here](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/auth) I found a simple `vertx` project that uses `apache-shiro` for auth. 
Here the user informations are stored inside `src/main/resources/vertx-users.properties` file like this:

```
user.tim = sausages,morris_dancer,developer,vtoons
role.developer=do_actual_work
role.vtoons=place_order
```

Is this a good approach to store user name and password in a file? Can we store these information in encrypted format or anywhere in a database. Can `apache-shiro` access these info from a db?
Please provide if you have some sample projects

Answer (score 0):

Better use LDAP or DB

use blog 
http://meri-stuff.blogspot.in/2011/04/apache-shiro-part-2-realms-database-and.html
for reference

Also this stackflow post [Configure shiro.ini for JDBC connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637907/configure-shiro-ini-for-jdbc-connection/34672286#34672286)